# Steering Windows 10 updates to an SD card in a 2GB/32GB mini PC

Tags: windows, updates, sd-card

I'm setting up a budget computer lab and I'm in possession of a bunch of windows 10 Mini pcs Z8350, with 2GB Ram and 32GB eMMC ss drives.

These little pcs work great to a point, after some quick optimization, and migration of larger files and applications to a SD card D: drive. I have Win 10 occupying 10-11GB. The problem I'm having is trying to persuade Windows 10 updates  to load to the D: drive and create the temporary folder in D: drive.  I haven't been able to find any information on a temporary execution folder, someone suggested there is a folder like C:\$WINDOWS.~BT

I'm using a common method to redirect updates from C: to D; using mklink /j C:Windows/SoftwareDistribution D:Windows/softwareDistribution.

I don't think this is a matter of the downloads getting saved to the SD card however, I suspect it's a matter of once the update runs it's looking for space to store or expand temporary files maybe?  The files seem to download with the progress bar, but during deployment/initialization (forgot the displayed term) is when this failure occurs.

Windows even opens a dialog at one point suggesting use of an external temporary drive, USB Flash or HDD, to temporarily facilitate the update files -- never showing the integral 64GB NTFS SD card D: drive.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Can you use [Windows Update Delivery Optimization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-delivery-optimization) to download updates through a master PC? It might decrease the amount of space required for the download file, though not for temporary files created during update.
- Download incremental updates on another PC, from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx), and move them to the D:\ drive for installation, or install over the network.
- For major (roll-up) updates, use [Microsoft's Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) tool, and make bootable USB's or SD's (which regrettably requires access to each PC) or mount the ISO on the network (if machines can be booted from LAN).
- Image one updated Mini and clone to the others.
- Use Linux instead, which take up about half the space of Windows 10 and has small daily incremental updates, rarely more than 300 MB. That updates software, as well, such as office suite, browser and email client, if a package manager is used. *{Sorry, I realize that switching OS is unlikely, but I couldn't resist pointing out the difference}.* ;-)

Comment: Thanks Dr., After I fully deleted the old C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder, 10+GB, the update 1709 finished.  The 1803 update then began after restart.  During the restart for 1803 I caught a glimpse of a few new graphics, the PC then restarted itself again, then a dialog indicated the OS was rolling back to a previous version.  It appears the updates were failing previously due to lack of free space in C: drive.

Comment: 1803 completed successfully.